# Keen-dataviz: Uncaught Requested parser does not exist

Tags: keen-io

I keep getting the following error: "Uncaught Requested parser does not exist" from the devtool console
and no chart is displayed on my dashboard.

JS Code:

```
var chart = new Keen.Dataviz()
  .el('#chart-01')
  .height(280)
  .title('Registered CSRs')
  .type('bar')
  .prepare();

// Fetch data from my server's API
var json = $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1.0/registered_csrs/nwg",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {

chart
  .data(jsonData)
  .render();
}
});
```

Here is the format of jsonData

```
$ curl -GET http://localhost:4000/api/v1.0/registered_csrs/nwg
[["Date", "Total", "Emergency", "High", "Medium", "Low"], 
["2016-02-01", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
["2016-03-01", 6, 0, 0, 6, 0], 
["2016-04-01", 11, 0, 1, 7, 3], 
["2016-05-01", 19, 0, 1, 16, 2], 
["2016-06-01", 27, 0, 12, 13, 2], 
["2016-07-01", 27, 3, 12, 12, 0], 
["2016-08-01", 25, 3, 8, 11, 3], 
["2016-09-01", 21, 4, 10, 5, 2], 
["2016-10-01", 19, 3, 4, 11, 1], 
["2016-11-01", 29, 4, 12, 12, 1], 
["2016-12-01", 26, 2, 9, 14, 1], 
["2017-01-01", 16, 1, 3, 11, 1], 
["2017-02-01", 22, 2, 8, 11, 1], 
["2017-03-01", 28, 2, 10, 14, 2], 
["2017-04-01", 15, 2, 6, 5, 2], 
["2017-05-01", 28, 2, 7, 18, 1], 
["2017-06-01", 22, 1, 11, 8, 2], 
["2017-07-01", 10, 1, 4, 5, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look
[Keen.io Dataviz to draw graph but keep getting error "Uncaught Requested parser does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594115/keen-io-dataviz-to-draw-graph-but-keep-getting-error-uncaught-requested-parser)

https://keen.io/docs/visualize/visualize-your-own-data/

Code below should work fine in your app

```
chart
  .data({result: jsonData})
  .render();
```